# How can we develop a software for various tablets with various density

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm Developing a Software for Android 4.0 Tablets. But Here various Size(7inch/10inch) Tablets and Various Density(800X480, 1280X800) Tablets Available in market.

How can i  design my Layout in XML file Suitable for all these types of Tablets.

Help me for Develop a Highly rich Designed software for all these types of Tablets in a Single way.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can't in a single way, Google allows you to specify different layout files for different sizes / densities.  See the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Question i looked for the Following URL, It will help for Different Screen Sizes and Densities.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 1):

google describes its best practices here : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html
this should give you great starting point

Answer (score 1):

You can access following page in android developer to receive sample code

```
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
```